# Combine HTML inputs?

Tags: html, forms

HTML form

I am trying to combine:

```
<input name="domain" id="domain" required="" type="hidden" value="domain.com">
<input name="username" id="username" required="" type="text">
```

to pass this combined information in the form as what is now:

```
<input name="user" id="user" required="" type="text">
```

Current code:

```
<input name="user" id="user" required="" type="text">
```

This requires the user to type both the domain and user name into the text box.
Example: domain.com\username

I would like to include the static domain “domain.com\” as hidden text to the input so they can just type the username.
Example: username

The code currently is:

```
<p>Username:</p>
<input name="user" id="user" required="" type="text">
```

Comment: Please provide the code for the backend that processes the form submission.

Comment: Apologies. I do not know how to discover this. I am trying to edit a HTML template file that was included with a new application that we are deploying.

Comment: Just put the domain in the script on the server that your form submits to. Do the append there.

Comment: I think the server side solution or something with jQuery would be better, but you could just use javascript, something like this.  Don't really like that though. `<form onsubmit = 'document.getElementById("domain").value = "domain.com\\" + document.getElementById("username").value'>
<input name="user" id="domain" required="" type="hidden">
<input id="username" required="" type="text" >
</form>`  Not really proper use.